# Append different actions in 1 framelayout through menu choices

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I am working on an Android application for tablets. I have 1 static menu with 6 buttons and 1 framelayout in which I wish to load the content related to a menu-item. What I want to achieve is that only the content of the framelayout changes but not the entire screen.

[image]

I think there are 2 choices here, 1. multiple activities or 2.multiple fragments in 1 activity. I would like some advise or suggestions wether these are the only options I have and if so, which one you would recommend and why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of problem you should use Fragments. [FragmentTransaction.replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29) is designed for this kind of interaction.

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, I googled it and found a usefull tutorial which I will try to complete.

Comment: If you find this answer useful please consider upvoting/accepting it

Comment: accepted it, can't upvote because I dont have enough points, regards